# dataExplorer::create_report produces html file that is blank

Tags: html, r

I am trying to create a HTML report from the DataExplorer::create_report(). The code is as follows

```
DataExplorer::create_report(iris, config = list(add_plot_qq = FALSE, global_ggtheme = quote(theme_minimal(base_size = 14))))
```

The code creates "report.html", which is blank when I open it in any browser. I am using the DataExplorer version 0.8.0

Comment: I've had some issues with this package myself. If you run `create_report(iris)` it works fine, the issue lies with the `config =` argument. From the GitHub vignette (https://github.com/boxuancui/DataExplorer/blob/master/vignettes/dataexplorer-intro.Rmd) the author actually uses `config = configure_report()`, unfortunately V 0.8 is not available to my R (3.5.2). Could you be using deprecated `config = list()`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The usage of configure_report instead of list() did work in this case.

Comment: Gangadharan, don't forget you can mark this as the accepted answer by clicking its check mark. Happy SO-ing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick's answer is correct. I made some updates in v0.8 to simplify report customization, i.e., [#87](https://github.com/boxuancui/DataExplorer/issues/87). However, I would like to use this section to provide a little more information on that. Please do not accept this as an answer.

`configure_report` helps you write less code in terms adding/removing sections, as well as editing themes. However, the output is no different from the `list` output from previous versions. If you want, you can still make your own list files and pass it to `create_report`. The template is here:

```
config <- list(
  "introduce" = list(),
  "plot_intro" = list(),
  "plot_str" = list(
    "type" = "diagonal",
    "fontSize" = 35,
    "width" = 1000,
    "margin" = list("left" = 350, "right" = 250)
  ),
  "plot_missing" = list(),
  "plot_histogram" = list(),
  "plot_qq" = list(sampled_rows = 1000L),
  "plot_bar" = list(),
  "plot_correlation" = list("cor_args" = list("use" = "pairwise.complete.obs")),
  "plot_prcomp" = list(),
  "plot_boxplot" = list(),
  "plot_scatterplot" = list(sampled_rows = 1000L)
)
```

After that, you can just call `create_report` as usual:

```
create_report(iris, config = config)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Boxuan. is there a way to change the colors of the bar in the plot_bar, plot_histogram etc. by tweaking the config ?

Comment: @Gangadharan Not at the moment, and I do not plan to enable that in the future. With current scope, bars and histograms are visualizing univariate information, and colors will duplicate the effects of bar length. However, if you want some other color in addition to the default black, you might want to replace the `plot_bar` function with a new `fill` argument.

Comment: @Gangadharan BTW, I really appreciate you accepting this as an answer, but I think the credit should go to Nick. As I said, my "answer" is just an extension. He gave you the right answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for the answer use: `config = configure_report()` instead of `config = list()`

```
DataExplorer::create_report(iris, 
config = configure_report(add_plot_qq = FALSE, 
global_ggtheme = quote(theme_minimal(base_size = 14))))
```